# Invariant Violation: "AppName" has not been registered. Android, React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, metro-bundler

I use monorepo for my project, and after hours I completed setup it for building on android, but it throws metro error, but on iOS it works fine.

Project structure:

- root

  - apps

    - react-native

      - index.js
      - package.json
    - web
- node_modules

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DByu8.png)

**metro.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..')
const projectRoot = __dirname

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  watchFolders: [workspaceRoot, projectRoot],
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'ios.js'],
    nodeModulesPaths: [
      path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
      path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
    ],
    disableHierarchicalLookup: true,
  },
}
```

**react-native info:**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 114.52 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 19.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.9.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.9.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.6.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.9.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/maksym/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 33
      Build Tools: 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.1
      System Images: android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a, android-32 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
    Xcode: 14.3.1/14E300c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 19.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: Not Found
    react-native: Not Found
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```